# remove objects from the array to insert in grid Drag and Drop

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

hello i am have two grids and i transfer records from first grid (book with field: id, author,price) to second grid (discount with field: id, author, price, new price ) with drag and drop, all good, but i am want next: when i am drag record from grid (book) and drop to grid (discount) records with the same field "id" (that are in both tables)  not inserted in grid (discount). I have an array of objects, how to make so that records with 'id' which is already in the table (discount) is not inserted.
I am make :

```
 listeners: {beforeDrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {}
```

but what write there ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your target grid `viewconfig` you can define listener for [`beforedrop`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop-event-beforedrop) event. In this listener you can get id of the dragged record and check if the id is not already in your array.

Array definiton:

```
var forbidenIds = [2, 3];
```

Target grid view config:

```
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
        dropGroup: 'group1',
    },
    listeners: {
        beforedrop: function(node, data) {
            // get id of dragged record
            var recordId = data.records[0].getId();                
            // search for record id in array
            var index = Ext.Array.indexOf(forbidenIds, recordId);
            return index === -1 ? true : false;
        }
    }
},
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3r8**

Comment: It will be work for single record, but i am allow user to select multiple records, in this case some of them are exist in forbidden list and some are not exist in this. If you know how to handle for multiple selection then pls tell me.